# Login & MFA form submission logic

Tags: php, multi-factor-authentication

I have a PHP login class that executes a series of functions in a chain, some of which can be skipped depending on certain conditions. The login process involves user inputs for email and password on the login form. However, after the login form is successfully processed, I need to prompt the user to enter a Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA) code if their browser/device is not found in the SQL database records.

Given that I'm using a single submission of the login form to execute the entire class, I'm faced with the challenge of how to efficiently reintroduce the form for the user to input the MFA code. What would be the most effective approach to accomplish this?

In short: Should I create a separate function for the MFA prompt, or is it possible to consolidate all processes within a single class?"

```
class LoginProcess {
private $errors = array();
private $notices = array();
private $accountId;
private $skipMFA = false;
private $skipRememberMe;

public function __construct($email, $password, $rememberMe) {
    $this->email = $email;
    $this->password = $password;
    $this->rememberMe = $rememberMe;

    $this->authInitiate($email, $password, $rememberMe); 
    if (empty($this->errors)) {
        $this->initiateMFA();
    }
    if (empty($this->errors) && !$this->skipMFA) {
        $this->generateMFA();
        $this->promptMFA();
    }
    if (empty($this->errors) && !$this->skipRememberMe) {
        $this->rememberMe();
    }
    if (empty($this->errors)) {
        $this->authUser();
    }       
}
```

The form:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
if (isset($_POST['Login'])) {
        $input = [
        'email' => $_POST['email'] ?? '',
        'password' => $_POST['password'] ?? '',
        'remember_me' => isset($_POST['remember_me']) ? true : false
    ];
    $loginProcess = new LoginProcess($input['email'], $input['password'], $input['remember_me']);
    $errors = $loginProcess->getErrors();
    $notices = $loginProcess->getNotices();
    $report = array('errors' => $errors, 'notices' => $notices);
    foreach ($report['errors'] as $error) {
        echo $error . '<br>';
    }
    foreach ($report['notices'] as $notice) {
        echo $notice . '<br>';
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Often the MFA code is, when used, entered in the same form as the email and password.